# How do I change the color of the "<", ">", and "<!DOCTYPE html> in intelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have tried "ctrl + alt + s" to take me to "Editor > Color Scheme > general" as well as "Editor > Color Scheme > language" and I can't find a setting for the carrots or the doctype. They are currently orange and it is driving me nuts. How can I change the color to ANYTHING else? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I love the 'Rainbow Brackets' plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor</kbd> -> <kbd>Color Scheme</kbd> -> <kbd>HTML</kbd> -> Tag